# Mule: Dataweave - date formatting from strings

Tags: datetime, mule, dataweave, mel

I've been searching around and can't find (or didn't recognize) a solution to this issue. I'm very new to MEL, so please be kind. :)

I am building a service that will accept 2 dates as strings. I want to be able to accept any (within reason) legitimate string representation of a date and coerce it to a specific format.

So far; everything I try results in errors. To somewhat simplify the process for now, I've started with a string in Dataweave instead of using the actual input for now.

I have this statement:
startDate: '2016/11/25 12:00:00' as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"} as :date {format: "yyyymmdd"},

I get this in response:
Cannot coerce a :date to a :string, caused by :Unsupported field: MinuteOfHour.

I also tried this:
startDate: '2016/11/25 12:00:00' as :date {format: "yyyymmdd"},

I get this response:
Cannot coerce a :string to a :date, caused by :Text '2016/11/25 12:00:00' could not be parsed at index 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use:

```
startDate: '2016/11/25 12:00:00' as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"} as :string {format: "yyyymmdd"}
```

Or:

```
startDate: '2016/11/25 12:00:00' as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"} as :localdatetime {format: "yyyymm"}
```

Since you don't have a timezone in your initial data, then I probably wouldn't use date/datetime as they need a timezone.

Shameless plug: I've made a video dealing with dates and DataWeave at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNCqzFEq9IY&t=2s

Comment: Thanks bunches!

The issue was 2 fold: matching the pattern and casting it to the correct output class.

Here is what I ended up with:

agreementDate: "$(flowVars.fullPayload.agreementDate) 12:00:00" as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} as :string {format: "yyyymmdd"}

Comment: Oh, thanks for the vid also .. bookmarked.

I do much better with examples than strict documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format "M/d/yyyy" it should work. If you use MM the formatter requires two digit for month

payload.DocDate as :date {format: "M/d/yyyy"}